# Android makefile can't find libs because of extra LOCAL_PATH in path

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

So I've been scratching my head for quite some time with this: basically, I have two Android makefile, one in my jni folder, and one in another folder that contains my native c++ code.

Thing is, for the following makefile,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

GENERATED_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../generated/release/api/Android

############################  Includes ############################

#------------------------------------------------------------------ Assimp

LOCAL_MODULE := Assimp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(GENERATED_PATH)/assimp/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(GENERATED_PATH)/assimp/lib/libassimp.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# More Libraries included....
#....
```

I get the following error:

> Android NDK: ERROR:jni/../../../appCommon/Android.mk:Assimp: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
>
> Android NDK: Check that jni/../../../appCommon/jni/../../../appCommon/../../generated/release/api/Android/assimp/lib/libassimp.a exists  or that its path is correct

What bugs me is that there's twice the `LOCAL_PATH` in the path where the ndk searches for the library.  I've already read about a few cases like this one (like using the `notdir` macro) but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

How can I specify correctly (and not manually) the correct directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem stems from the `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` script, which looks for the lib in the following path: `$(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)`

Thus, a simple workaround that worked is to have separate variables for the directories, like that:

```
GENERATED_PATH := ../../generated/release/api/Android
GENERATED_INCLUDE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(GENERATED_PATH)
```

and then use them like that:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := Assimp
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(GENERATED_INCLUDE_PATH)/assimp/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(GENERATED_PATH)/assimp/lib/libassimp.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```